# Correct syntax for addressing JSON object in Jekyll _data file

Tags: json, jekyll, liquid

I am creating a page in Jekyll and attempting to use data in a JSON file stored in Jekyll's "_data" folder. The JSON file is "/_data/objectsandproperties.json" and contains:

```
{ 
    "objectA": { "propertyA": "FooA", "propertyB": "BarA" },
    "objectB": { "propertyA": "FooB", "propertyB": "BarB" },
    "objectC": { "propertyA": "FooC", "propertyB": "BarC" }
}
```

I would like to output a list formatted like this:

```
<dl>
    <dt>objectA</dt>
        <dd>propertyA: FooA</dd>
        <dd>propertyB: BarA</dd>
    <dt>objectB</dt>
        <dd>propertyA: FooB</dd>
        <dd>propertyB: BarB</dd>
    <dt>objectC</dt>
        <dd>propertyA: FooC</dd>
        <dd>propertyB: BarC</dd>
</dl>
```

I am currently using Liquid tags in my markdown file like this:

```
{% for objects in site.data.objectsandproperties %}
<dl>
  {% for object in objects %}
  <dt>Object names: {{ object }}</dt>
      <dd>propertyA: {{ object.propertyA }}</dd>
      <dd>propertyB: {{ object.propertyB }}</dd>
  {% endfor %}
</dl>
{% endfor %}
```

This is not working as the object is not "objectA" but the entire objectA object with properties etc.

I don't have access to the script that creates the JSON file so I cannot add a label or make it an array etc. I'm hoping I can get this to work with Liquid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `inspect` filter to better understand what we are working with :

```
{% for object in site.data.objectsandproperties %}

  {{ object | inspect }} 
  >> returns an array like :
  >> ["objectA", {"propertyA"=>"FooA", "propertyB"=>"BarA"}]

  name : {{ object.first }} or {{ object[0] }}
  properties : {{ object.last}} or {{ object[1] }}

{% endfor %}
```

Your code can look like :

```
<dl>
{% for object in site.data.objectsandproperties %}
  <dt>Object names: {{ object | first }}</dt>
  <dd>propertyA: {{ object.last.propertyA }}</dd>
  <dd>propertyB: {{ object.last.propertyB }}</dd>
{% endfor %}
</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks @David Jacquel I'd not come across the inspect filter. I'll try this tonight, it looks like it does exactly what I need:-)

Answer (score 2):

You can access and print keys of data by utilizing the attributes of the `forloop` object:

```
<dl>
{%- for object in site.data.objectsandproperties %}
  {%- for prop in object %}
    {%- if forloop.first %}
    <dt>{{ prop }}</dt>
    {%- else %}
      {%- for subprop in prop %}
        <dd>{{ subprop[0] }}: {{ subprop[1] }}</dd>
      {%- endfor %}
    {%- endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
{%- endfor %}
</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks @ashmaroli, I can access the object's properties, I just can't display the name of the object.

As the for loop goes through the N objects in the JSON, I need to print out the name of the object. So I would be able say: 

Name: objectA
Name: objectB
Name: objectC

I don't think I can do that with the syntax you suggest.

I've fixed it by changing the structure of the JSON so I have an array or a name/value pair to work with but in this instance I can't change the JSON.

How do I loop through a JSON file displaying the text of the key for each object?

Comment: @DugFalby I've revamped my answer to output your desired markup for *any* given JSON data.

Comment: Thanks @ashmaroli I'll try this hen I get back to my machine this evening. Thanks for clarifying, this looks good and v useful that the method can be used to walk any JSON object structure:-)